# How to get All Math Numbers in Italics?

Tags: math-mode, fourier

I am currently trying to get all numbers in math mode in italics. However, I find no way of re-defining the numbers 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 to make them italics as long as they are in a math environment. I am using the Fourier font, both for text and math. Though it's not quite useful, here is a small MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
% PACKAGES LOADING
\usepackage[sloped]{fourier} % To customise font.
\begin{document}
$0123456789$
\end{document}
```

The numbers in the output (below) are of course not in italics, which is what I wish.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

PS: I am aware that this may be considered bad typesetting practices, but I want to see how it looks in my document anyway.

PS2: I found several closely-related questions in the site; but none of them addressed this question in particular. If this is already answered in the site; I am sorry: I never saw it in my search.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

normally you would have been able to allocate digits to the `letter` alphabet but that doesn't seem to give italic digits in this setup, so I allocated a new math alphabet.

```
\documentclass{article}
% PACKAGES LOADING
\usepackage[sloped]{fourier} % To customise font.
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathit}{T1}{fut\mathfamilyextension}{m}{it}%

\DeclareMathSymbol{0}{\mathord}{mathit}{`0}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}{\mathord}{mathit}{`1}
\DeclareMathSymbol{2}{\mathord}{mathit}{`2}
\DeclareMathSymbol{3}{\mathord}{mathit}{`3}
\DeclareMathSymbol{4}{\mathord}{mathit}{`4}
\DeclareMathSymbol{5}{\mathord}{mathit}{`5}
\DeclareMathSymbol{6}{\mathord}{mathit}{`6}
\DeclareMathSymbol{7}{\mathord}{mathit}{`7}
\DeclareMathSymbol{8}{\mathord}{mathit}{`8}
\DeclareMathSymbol{9}{\mathord}{mathit}{`9}
\begin{document}
$0123456789$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better `\mathalpha`? Also `\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet` is needed.

Comment: @egreg well `\mathalpha` or `\mathord` depends on the definition of "All" in the question. Not sure about `\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet`? that's for making a `\mathxxx` alphabet command out of a symbol font but this needs the other way I've declared a symbol font, oh you mean redeclare `\mathit` to use this and save a fam? I suppose so...

Comment: Carlisle's answer works as expected and solves the question. I do not know how using \mathalpha would improve the answer; but I am  willing to know it.

Comment: @Héctor as it is the digits will always be in that font even if you use `\mathrm{1}` etc if it was `\mathalpha` instead then they would start in that font but obey font change commands

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: So... As long as I do not change the font of the numbers further, this makes no difference; but as soon as I want to apply some other changes to the numbers, this makes a difference. Am I right? So far, I am not applying any other changes to the numbers, but it could be the case in the future. Should I then change "\mathord" for "\mathalpha" in your answer? Would this be sufficient?

Comment: @Héctor yes....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I just noticed a problem. When typsetting italic numbers; the spacing between the last number and parentheses, brackets and so on is too small. Is it possible to correct for this?

Comment: @Héctor not easily (anything is possible of course, you could make them active and look ahead for `)` but the more tricky macros you add the more things will break)

Comment: Good to know; I appreciate your point. I have asked a new question to solve this issue here:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361202/italic-correction-with-italic-numbers-in-math-mode